# Learning about inheritance in Java, unsure how to use super.toString() properly?

Tags: java, oop, subclass, superclass

I am new to Java, working on a lab to practice simple hierarchy of classes along with implementation and use of inheritance. I have Main.Java as the driver, Taxpayer.Java which is the superclass, and I'm working on WeeklyTaxPayer.java as the first of three subclasses. The WeeklyTaxPayer subclass has the public computeStateTax method that which of course calculates the tax depending on what the user enters.

What I am stuck on is getting what's in the subclass to print. The directions explain as follows:

"The WeeklyTaxpayer class must have a public toString method that concatenates together and returns the following: The string returned by invoking the parent class toString method to get a string that includes the values of all the member variables for a WeeklyTaxpayer instance."

There is a public String toString() method in the TaxPayer Superclass which prints out the rest of the users information (name, ssn, gross pay) But I cannot get it to print out the tax that the subclass should be calculating.

In the WeeklyTaxPayer subclass I have:

```
 @Override
 public String toString(){
 return super.toString() + df.format(computeWeeklyTax(grossPay, taxPayerType));
```

But the return always is zero for the tax. Let me know if I should add anymore of my code, I'm new to this website and didn't want it to be too lengthy. Thank you for any help.

*Updated* (**Note: I realize that the ComputeTax() method found in the TaxPayer and Main will result in zero, but the lab asks for that before creating the WeeklyTax Subclass "Change the computeTax method so that it does nothing except return 0.0." I assumed it did this because my computeWeeklyTax method would override it somehow)**

TaxPayer.Java

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Taxpayer {

// Instance variables
protected String name;
protected int ssNumber;

protected double grossPay;
protected static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$#,###.00");

/**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param name - name of the tax payer
   * 
   * @param ssN - ssN of the tax payer
   * @param gp - gross pay
    */
public Taxpayer(String name, int ssN, double gp) {
this.name = name;
this.ssNumber = ssN;

this.grossPay = gp;
}


/**
   * Returns the name
   */
public String getName() {
return name;
}
/**
   * Returns the ssNumber
*/
public String getSSNumber() {
String ssnStr = ssNumber + "";
ssnStr = ssnStr.substring(0, 3) + "-" + ssnStr.substring(3, 6) + "-" + ssnStr.substring(6);
return ssnStr;
}
/**
   * Returns the taxRate
*/

/**
   * Returns the grossPay
   */
public double getGrossPay() {
return grossPay;
}

/**
   * Computes the tax and returns it
   * @return
   */
public double computeTax() {
return (getGrossPay() - getGrossPay());
}



public String toString() {
return "Taxpayer Name: " + name + ", SSN: " + getSSNumber() + "Taxpayer Type: " + this.getClass().getName() + ", Gross Pay: " + df.format(grossPay)
+ ", Tax payable: " + df.format(computeTax());
}
}
```

WeeklyTaxPayer.Java:

```
public class WeeklyTaxpayer extends Taxpayer{


    public WeeklyTaxpayer(String name, int ssN, double gp) {
        super(name, ssN, gp);
    }

    public double computeWeeklyTax(double gp, char taxPayerType){

                     double stateTax = 0;

         while (taxPayerType == 'W')  

         {
          if ((grossPay >= 0) || (grossPay < 154))
          {
          stateTax = grossPay - 0;
          stateTax = grossPay * .0400;
          stateTax = grossPay + 0;


          }
          else if ((grossPay >= 154) || (grossPay < 212))
          {
              stateTax = grossPay - 154;
              stateTax = grossPay * .0450;
              stateTax = grossPay + 6.15;

          }
          else if ((grossPay >= 212)||(grossPay < 250))
          {
              stateTax = grossPay - 212;
          stateTax = grossPay * .0525;
          stateTax = grossPay + 8.75;

          }
          else if ((grossPay >= 250)||(grossPay < 385))
          {
              stateTax = grossPay - 250;
          stateTax = grossPay * .0590;
          stateTax = grossPay + 10.77;

          }

          else if ((grossPay >= 385)||(grossPay < 1731))
          {
          stateTax = grossPay - 385;
          stateTax = grossPay * .0685;
          stateTax = grossPay + 18.71;

          }
          else if ((grossPay >= 1731)||(grossPay < 1923))
          {
              stateTax = grossPay - 1731;
          stateTax = grossPay * .0764;
          stateTax = grossPay + 110.92;

          }
          else if ((grossPay >= 1923)||(grossPay < 2885))
          {
              stateTax = grossPay - 1923;
          stateTax = grossPay * .0814;
          stateTax = grossPay + 125.62;

          }
          else if ((grossPay >= 2885))
          {
              stateTax = grossPay - 2885;
          stateTax = grossPay * .0935;
          stateTax = grossPay + 203.92;

          }
         }

        return stateTax;

      }

        public char taxPayerType;
@Override
   public String toString()    {
        return super.toString() + df.format(computeWeeklyTax(grossPay, taxPayerType)); 
        }
}
```

Main.Java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Main {


public static String getTaxpayerTypeName(char taxPayerType) {

            // based on the value of taxPayerType, returning full type name

            if (taxPayerType == 'W') {

                  return "Weekly";

            } else if (taxPayerType == 'B') {

                  return "Biweekly";

            } else if (taxPayerType == 'M') {

                  return "Monthly";

            } else {

                  return "Try Again!";  
            }
}

    /** Creates a new instance of Main */
    public Main() {
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String Type = "";
          String taxType = "";

        final int MAX_NUMBER = 5;
        Taxpayer t1 = null;   // Variable to hold an instance of the Taxpayer class
        Taxpayer t2 = null;   // Same as above
        Taxpayer t3 = null;   // Same
        Taxpayer t4 = null;   // Same
        Taxpayer t5 = null;   // Same


        Taxpayer t = null;
        DecimalFormat prec2 = new DecimalFormat("$#.00");
        DecimalFormat prec1 = new DecimalFormat("#.0%");
        String nameStr = "";   // Holds taxpayer name entered by user
        String ssnNumStr = ""; // Holds taxpayer's SSNnumber as string, entered by user
        int ssnNum = 0;         // Taxpayer's ssnumber as int
        String tRateStr = ""; // Taxpayer's tax rate as string, entered by user
        double trate = 0.0;    // Taxpayer's tax rate as double
        String grossStr = ""; // Taxpayer's gross pay as string, entered by user
        double grossPay = 0.0; // Taxpayer's gross pay as double

        int count = 0;         // The number of taxpayers created
        String outputStr = ""; // String for output display to user
        String outputStr2 = "";// String for output display to user
        String msgStr = "";    // Holds message for display to user
        int resp = 0;          // User's response from showConfirmDialog method




        while (true) {   



// Loop to input data on each taxpayer
            count++;



            // Read in name from user as a string
            nameStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter taxpayer name");

             Type = JOptionPane
              .showInputDialog("Enter CAPITALIZED LETTER for your type: W for Weekly, B for BiWeekly, M for Monthly: ");

      char taxPayerType = Type.charAt(0);

                  taxType = getTaxpayerTypeName(taxPayerType);

            // Read in ID number from user as a string
            ssnNumStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter SSN number");
            // Convert from type String to type int
            ssnNum = Integer.parseInt(ssnNumStr.trim());



            // Read in gross pay from user as a string
            grossStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter gross pay");
            // Convert from type String to type double
            grossPay = Double.parseDouble(grossStr.trim());


                     switch (taxPayerType) {
                case 'W': t = new WeeklyTaxpayer(nameStr, ssnNum, grossPay);
               // case 'B': t = new BiWeeklyTaxpayer(nameStr, ssnNum, grossPay);;
               // case 'M': t = new MonthlyTaxpayer(nameStr, ssnNum, grossPay);;


            }

            // Assign new Taxpayer object to next available Taxpayer variable

            switch (count) {
                case 1: t1 = t; break;
                case 2: t2 = t; break;
                case 3: t3 = t; break;
                case 4: t4 = t; break;
                case 5: t5 = t; break;

            }
            outputStr += count + ". " + t.toString() + "\n";

            if (count < MAX_NUMBER) {
                msgStr = "\nMax number of allowed taxpayers is: " + MAX_NUMBER + "\nContinue?";

                resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, outputStr + msgStr, "Confirm",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if (resp == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                    break;
            } else {
                msgStr = "Program cannot handle any more additional taxpayers.";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr + msgStr, "Results",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                break;
            }
        }

        outputStr2 = "Taxpayer list:\n";
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
            switch (i) {
                case 1: t = t1; break;
                case 2: t = t2; break;
                case 3: t = t3; break;
                case 4: t = t4; break;
                case 5: t = t5; break;

            }
            outputStr2 += "\n" + i + ". " + t.getName() +

                    "\nTaxpayer Type: " + t.getClass().getName() + 

                    "\n    SSN: " + t.getSSNumber() +

                    "\n    Gross Pay: " + prec2.format(t.getGrossPay()) +
                    "\n    Tax for Pay Period: " + prec2.format(t.computeTax()) + "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr2, "TAXPAYERS",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow cha0ticg00d! It's a little hard to fully debug without the rest of the code, so if posting the `TaxPayer` and `WeeklyTaxPayer` code is possible, that would be useful.

Comment: So you're saying that `df.format(computeWeeklyTax(grossPay, taxPayerType))` is returning the string `"0"`? If so, then your problem exists in either `df.format()` (unlikely) or `computeWeeklyTax` (highly likely). What does the latter look like?

Comment: Thank you for the Welcome. I updated the question to include all the code I have thus far and further explaining where I'm stuck. Thank you for your help

Comment: What you've explained so far is very confusing. Are you sure you're meant to create the `computeWeeklyTax` method? The way it looks at the moment, I'd say you're meant to override `computeTax()` and then override `toString()` to add in any extra class members within the sub-class.

Comment: I agree the way this lab is worded is very confusingly. I'm sorry, I did my best to summarize the directions. But yes, we are told to create a public method that computes the state tax, which I called computeWeeklyTax.